# update mysql from dataset/datatable with vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, dataset

I am new to vb.net and I am trying to update mysql table from a txt file using vb.net. So far I've found code here and there and been able to extract the data from the txt file, now my question is how to update mysql from the same dataset or xml file. Here is my code to populate the datagrid/dataset/xml file. Can you tell me what is the easiest way to update mysql assuming "Orden" is my primary key in mysql.

```
     OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text File|*.txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Open File..."
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "trackings"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        Dim DT As New DataTable
        DT.Columns.Add("COD")
        DT.Columns.Add("Tracking")
        DT.Columns.Add("Fecha")
        DT.Columns.Add("Orden")
        DT.Columns.Add("Estatus")


        Dim Lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

        For Each Line As String In Lines
            Dim ItemsOf() As String = Split(Line, " ")
            ItemsOf = Line.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            If ItemsOf(0) = "N" Then ItemsOf(4) = 3 Else ItemsOf(4) = 6
            Dim NRow As String() = {ItemsOf(0), ItemsOf(1), ItemsOf(2), ItemsOf(3), ItemsOf(4)}
            DT.Rows.Add(NRow)
        Next Line
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DT
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(DT)
        ds.WriteXml("c:\x.xml")
    End If
```

Any help is appreciated! And with some code even more! =0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, it looks like your flat file isn't formatted in a complicated manner.  If this is the case, you can skip generating the XML file altogether.  Load the file directly onto MySQL using "[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)".

If necessary, load onto a staging table first, and then perform the update using that table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was actually looking to use the mysql update since I have more columns on my table and insert in another table from the same line. After playing around I found a way to do it. Maybe it's not the best way to do it, but at least is working... If you know a best approach please let me know. Here is my code: